# Mongo $sort and $count getting worse with new releases

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After upgrading my mongo server from 3.4 to 4.2, some aggregations using $sort and $count are now very slow to execute. To be sure it was related to the upgrade I installed several versions of Mongo locally and tried the same aggregation on the same amount of data and here's the results :

```
db.getCollection('devices').aggregate([
{ $lookup: { from: "sites", localField: "_id", foreignField: "devices", as: "site" } }, 
{ $unwind: { path: "$site", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "site._id", foreignField: "sites", as: "users" } },
{ $count: "count"}
])

Mongo version     Time
3.4            => 0.47s
3.6            => 0.632s
4.0            => 0.641s
4.2            => 2.98s
4.3.5          => 3.1s


db.getCollection('devices').aggregate([
{ $lookup: { from: "sites", localField: "_id", foreignField: "devices", as: "site" } },
{ $unwind: { path: "$site", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "site._id", foreignField: "sites", as: "users" } },
{ $sort: { _id: 1 } },
{ $skip: 0 },
{ $limit: 20 }
])

Mongo version     Time
3.4            => 0.476s
3.6            => 0.581s
4.0            => 0.669s
4.2            => 2.89s
4.3.5          => 3.24s
```

I have indexes on every fields used by the $lookup
I know that the $sort should be put at the first stages of the pipeline to use the index but as this query is written dynamically, the sorted field is not always on _id and can be one of the field coming from the $lookup, also $match may be added dynamically between the stages, eg. $match: {"users.type": "customer"}

My real questions are "How can the performances getting so worse by upgrading mongo ? Am I missing something obvious ?"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try running query plan on both versions? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/

Comment: I just did run an explain() on the 3.4 and 4.2 versions. The result is the same with only new sections introduced with the 4.2 as "serverInfo", "queryHash" and "planCacheKey".

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot more information about what exactly you benchmarked it is impossible to say what is responsible for the difference in elapsed time. Does the elapsed time include the time for the driver to connect to the database?

> How can the performances getting so worse by upgrading mongo ?

Generally speaking, new features are constantly being added to all software that is under active development, hence it is reasonable to expect that an individual operation may get slower over time either because it itself does more work to accommodate the growth in features, or because there is overhead around it due to feature growth elsewhere in the system.

Comment: I run the aggregates from robo3T the same way for all the mongo version. Everything runs locally. Also, this is a subset of the production data, when using the full collections the process time jump from a few seconds with 3.4 to more than 2 minutes with the 4.2

Comment: You could establish a consistent baseline between the different server versions by benchmarking a trivial query and ensuring it runs it approximately the same time, then simplify the query you care about to identify which parts of it account for the execution time variance between server versions.

Comment: Yes, the problematic parts are the $count and $sort, without them the aggregations take approximately the same time between the different versions. I understand that performances could be alterated by the addition of new features, but taking 2 minutes to count the ~20k elements of an aggregation seems really bad :-(

Comment: I imagine if you create a reproduce case that is easy for other people to run and post it on https://community.mongodb.com/, someone is likely to investigate it.